# Join three tables / SQL

Tags: sql, join

I know joining three tables already exists as topics here, but I don't know how to implement those in my example... here is what I have:

```
$id = _GET[ 'id' ]
```

**table1:**

```
mid  |  name   
11              . . .  johan
22    . . .   zoki
```

**table2:**

```
id    |  mid | time
1    . . 11   . 1234
1  .   . 22.. ..1111
2...   ..11.... 1112
```

**table3:**

```
id | num2 | surname
1 . 212 . pogancic
2 . 111 . pajser
```

What I need: to load all things from 3 tables. My try was:

```
SELECT *
FROM table2 JOIN
     table1
     ON table1.mid=table2.mid
WHERE id=$id
```

But in that way I can't get 'surname'...tried also with adding another JOIN:

```
SELECT *
FROM table2 JOIN
     table1
     ON table1.mid=table2.mid JOIN
     table3
     ON table3.id=table2.id
WHERE id=$id
```

But without positive results; any help?

**EDIT:** With the `WHERE id=$id` I can't get the results; it seems there's a problem, not in a JOIN

Comment: How have you determined that the problem is not in the WHERE clause?

Comment: in WHERE im using id=$id from _get parameter, i dont think it has anything to do with all ?

Comment: For the above data set-up what is the desired results....it Will be helpful for implementation

Comment: if you mean the error, it's: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given on line 121

Comment: @jocanis Smart003 is asking, "What did you expect your results to look like?"

Comment: i just want to stamp surname with correct id...but @ScottHunter, im a bit confused, when i remove WHERE with id=$id, i can get surnames, but with that condition, im getting the error (with 2 joins in code)

Comment: Try to qualify `id` in the `WHERE` clause: `WHERE table2.id=$id` It's likely, when you change your PHP code, that it outputs SQL errors you'll get something in the fashion of "column expression `id` is ambiguous"...

Comment: Hi. What does "load all things from 3 tables" mean? What do "without positive results" & "i cant get the results" mean? Please read & act on [mcve]. Please clarify via edits, not comments. Use language to clearly say what you mean. Including what you want the query to return--what has to be true about values in a row for it to be in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks good. Maybe something is wrong with your data. The data you describe is:

```
create table table1 (
  mid int,
  name varchar(20)
);

insert into table1 (mid, name) values (11, 'johan');
insert into table1 (mid, name) values (22, 'zoki');

create table table2 (
  id int,
  mid int,
  time int
);

insert into table2 (id, mid, time) values (1, 11, 1234);
insert into table2 (id, mid, time) values (1, 22, 1111);
insert into table2 (id, mid, time) values (2, 11, 1112);

create table table3 (
  id int,
  num2 int,
  surname varchar(20)
);

insert into table3 (id, num2, surname) values (1, 212, 'pogancic');
insert into table3 (id, num2, surname) values (2, 111, 'pajser');
```

Therefore, the query should be:

```
select t1.*, t2.*, t3.*
  from table2 t2
  join table1 t1 on t2.mid = t1.mid
  join table3 t3 on t3.id = t2.id
```

Result:

```
mid  name   id  mid  time  id  num2  surname
---  -----  --  ---  ----  --  ----  --------
11   johan  1   11   1234  1   212   pogancic
11   johan  1   11   1234  1   212   pogancic
11   johan  2   11   1112  2   111   pajser
22   zoki   1   22   1111  1   212   pogancic
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes thats what i need. just without two mids and ids. 
But i missed WHERE condition. With my two JOINS + WHERE id=$id i'm getting error. When i remove WHERE i'm getting everything; of course with not correct IDS, but again...

Answer (score -1):

Ok i got it working. Thanks to  @Scott Hunter for reminding me. Problem was:

WHERE id=$id -> WHERE table2.id=$id

Comment: Please read [answer] & edit this to clearly explain how/why it answers the question. Please also clarify what the question was.